# Basic programmation : My function doesn't return the expected output (Angular - firebase - JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'm probably going to ask something very easy. I'm a beginner in programming. I have a function called getUserName.

I initialized an output "Hello my friend". I'm using function into my function but my output is not changing. At the end, I'm returning the same "Hello my friend" output while I should get a LastName.

```
  getUserName(){
    this.output='Hello my friend';
    firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild("email").equalTo('test1@test.com').on('value', function (snapshot) {
       //snapshot would have list of NODES that satisfies the condition
          console.log(snapshot.val())
        console.log('-----------');

       //go through each item found and print out the lastName
       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              //this will be the actual lastName value found
              console.log(childData.lastName);

              //Here my console.log is not working, this.output doesn't take the lastName value.
              this.output = childData.lastName;
              console.log("Not working one : " + this.output);
        });
  });
        return this.output;
  }
```

Comment: I believe what's happening here is that the Firebase call is asynchronous, so your return statement happens before the query is performed. One way to solve this is to have `getUserName()` accept a callback function as an argument, which you then call with the result of the last name value. Try adding a console.log statement immediately before the return statement, and see whether that is written before or after the '-----------' console statement.

Comment: and a screenshot of ur database

Comment: The thing is the  "console.log(childData.lastName);" display the result I want. Can it still be because the return statement happens before the query is performed ?

Comment: @Peter you shouldn't tell people to add screenshots of textual information. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon check all the Firebase questions, they always add a screenshot of the database.. I'm not saying code, Firebase has its own console so we need to see the database to know what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this issue is happening because of the return itself.

Code execution flow is like below

1) called method and intialized the output variable
2) called async operation as it is async it wont wait for it operation to get completed
3) return output
4) async operation might received response from firebase and it print console and assign the value to output variable but it is of no use because method already returned output in step three

Solution:

1) use async await concept and make your async operation complete fully 
 2) change return statement inside the subscription